# How to avoid business logic in frontend while keeping frontend interactive

Tags: frontend, domain-driven-design

I am a DDD amateur, and I'm not sure I phrased the question correctly, or whether this even concerns DDD, but here is what has been bugging me about trying to implement DDD in my project.

Let's say my system is a sales order management system, where user can input sales orders with multiple lines for each order. Now the line amount can be in the base currency (of our client) or in a foreign currency, in which case it needs to be converted to the base currency by multiplying with a pre-determined exchange rate varying from month to month.

I think this amount conversion is a business rule and therefore should be in the domain layer. However I also want my user to be able to enter the amount in foreign currency and then have the amount in base currency automatically calculated and filled out in the form without the need to explicitly submit any data. This looks like it needs to be carried out on the frontend, and therefore violates the "no business rule in the frontend" rule.

How would you go about implementing this?

Comment: What about having an API that gives you the exchange rate?

Comment: @MaxSC Yes that is an option I thought of, and there's nothing inherently wrong with it. But then the business rule of actually enforcing that the amount in the base currency is correctly calculated from the amount in the foreign currency and the exchange rate would be on the frontend. And for some reason it does not sit well with me, which is why I am asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are probably 3 main scenarios:

1. **The logic already exists on the backend**. In that case most obvious route when wanting to avoid duplication is to expose an API on the backend allowing the client to leverage that logic. The multi-tier interaction can usually be made almost transparent to the user assuming latency remains reasonable.
2. **It's business logic, but the backend doesn't care.** In your example, if the backend always work in a base currency (e.g. USD) and the exchange rate is only needed on the client then implement such logic in the client only. It becomes a client-specific concern. It's still business logic though (business logic is not limited to a specific tier), so it should be maintained as such in the client. For instance, keep that logic in client-side services rather than mixed with presentation concerns. Implement unit tests as well since it's core logic.
3. **It's business logic on the backend, but there's too much latency.** In that case you must duplicate as much logic as needed on the client to meet the performance goal. You could either do that manually or through code generation strategies (e.g. transpile one language to another).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I guess I will go with having the backend expose a CalculateBaseCurrencyAmount kind of API, then letting the frontend call it each time the ForeignCurrencyAmount is changed. Somehow the fact that the calculation initiating and value setting still needs to be done by the frontend does not put me fully at ease, but I guess that's just something I have to live with when developing for the web. I will wait a bit for more replies before flagging answer. Thank you again.

Comment: Don't forget to validate the inputs from the client on the backend if needed. Don't just trust what it sent.